# Material, UV and objects - Interface question

Tags: texturing, uv, interface, navigation

A newbie here.

I create an object > Add an UV map > Apply some texture. I then duplicate the object, The 2 objects are rendered properly, they show the material correctly.

I then want to change the alignment of the material in one of the objects so I select the object > go to Edit mode >  open the UV editor. Here I am expecting to see the UV mapping I previously added and also the texture file so I can move the map to align the texture, instead it shows no material and no uv map.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Thanks for any advise

Comment: Switch to Edit mode.

Comment: Ok, it was dumb. I did select the object and then switched to Edit mode but the object was getting de-selected so I had to re-select it while in Edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot your 3D viewport is in Object Mode, for what you're describing you want it to be in Edit Mode:

[image]